# Type introspection - get property or fields information

Tags: c#, .net, polymorphism, system.reflection

if you do need to get a required information, being a `field` or `propertie`s  `values` / `names`,

HOW could you do it **not** by using `System.Reflection` ?

```C#
public class anyClass
{
    public const string UserID  = "usrID",
                        UserName = "usrName";
}
```

so it happens, as i really wanted to know if it's possible to avoid using `reflection`,

i have conducted a little research and ..seems to me that, the correct Term for my *mission* is

**[Type introspection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_introspection)**   <sub>( a **dediced tag** does not exitst here in `SO`)</sub>

`Introspection` should not be confused with `reflection`,

which goes a step further and is the ability for a program to manipulate the values,

meta-data, `properties` and/or `functions` of an `object` at runtime.

by using system reflection i could access `Fields`- `values`, as in this example code :

```C#
    var ac = new anyClass();
    public List<string> anyClassFieldsValuesList()
    {
      // sorry this was the one for the class above
      return typeof(anyClass).GetFields()
                     .Select(f =>f.GetValue(ac).ToString()).ToList<string>();


     // this would do for nested class
     // return typeof(anyClass).GetNestedTypes()
                    .First(t => String.Compare(t.Name, "anyNested", true) == 0)
                    .GetFields()
                    .Select(f => f.GetValue(ac).ToString())
                    .ToList<string>();
    }
```

Does .net offers us a usage of tools or other approach to get that information in a less *expensive* way ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The emphasis on *expensive* suggests that performance is your main concern. If that is the case, there are libraries out there that exist to remove the overhead of reflection, by caching of metadata and meta-programming. But they are often very specific in their intent.

For example, [FastMember](http://nuget.org/packages/FastMember) will help with knowing what members exist, and allowing access to their values (without the usual associated overhead of reflection), *but*: it doesn't help with the `GetNestedTypes` bit.

For example, to get all values from a given object, based on what `ac` actually *is*:

```
// requires FastMember
var accessor = TypeAccessor.Create(ac.GetType());
var values = accessor.GetMembers()
        .Select(member => accessor[ac, member.Name]).ToList();
```

Comment: I should note that this uses some `System.Reflection` *internally*, but it uses it in some very particular ways to minimise net overhead **significantly** compared to raw reflection

Comment: @MarkGravell, yes i did read about that , in **some Way** you **could** get less `performance` *hit* , meaning many times less ...this is little *old* http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163759.aspx (the diagram shows some results which i am not familiar with any of then (;)

Comment: @LoneXcoder indeed, which is what FastMember tries to do; by [my measurements here](http://marcgravell.blogspot.co.uk/2012/01/playing-with-your-member.html) (near the end), it is 120 times faster than regular reflection, only 5 times slower than static C# ... which means it is pretty damned fast.

Comment: i jumped on the mission to be your **1k** user to have downloaded it (: had the honor ... Congrats

Answer (score 0):

It looks look you need  [dynamic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264736.aspx) type

Comment: The fact that they are looking at nested types and fields *probably* means that isn't going to be directly applicable.